# Removing a table border-top without using CSS

Tags: html, html-table, border

I need to get rid of this table's top border, but I can't use CSS for that.

I've tried using `border-top-width="0"` inside the `<table>` or after the style="width:100%;" but the border line just wont go away

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50%">Name</td>
            <td style="width:25%">Quantity</td>
            <td style="width:25%">Value</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `style= border-top: none` in the table tag